# how Fetch Users from Active Directory with a lot of users

Tags: c++, active-directory, server

I want to know how Fetch Users from Active Directory with a lot of users?
i use this code

```
hr = ADsGetObject(L"WinNT://localhost",
IID_IADsContainer, (void**) &pCont );

if ( !SUCCEEDED(hr) ) 

{

   return hr;
}

_variant_t var;
IEnumVARIANTPtr pEnum; 
ADsBuildEnumerator (pCont,&pEnum);
int cnt=0;
ULONG ulFetched = 0L;
_variant_t vChild;
while((SUCCEEDED(ADsEnumerateNext(pEnum, 1, &vChild, &ulFetched)) && ulFetched==1)) 

{
///////////

}
```

but it takes a long time for get users from server(40k users)

Comment: How long does it take? You can try using LDAP to query users in AD https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367016(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: tnq ,it was useful